# Visual Studio 2017 tag completion

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In past editions of Visual Studio, I recall being able to autocomplete my tags by entering the tag name + . + class name. + tab
e.g.
`div.container -> tab`
would yield
`<div class="container"></div>`

I've added a number of extensions including ReSharper and Web Essentials but I'm still not seeing the desired behavior.

Is there another extension or setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

[ZenCoding](https://github.com/madskristensen/ZenCodingVS) (Mads Kristensen)

I wish I could thank Mads personally for his contributions to .NET development

ZenCodingsVS (Visual Studio Extension)
https://github.com/madskristensen/ZenCodingVS